# Can't switch workspaces by scrolling over bottom right screen corner (ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: gnome, mouse, workspace-switcher, 21.10

Running Ubuntu 21.10 I select GNOME or GNOME on Xorg when logging in. Gnome version is 40.4.0.

I don't like a dock cluttering the screen, so I have installed `vanilla-gnome-desktop` and rely on Gnome extensions. For example, the excellent Desktop Icons NG (DING) gives me desktop icons to start programs and manage mounted network drives. To list running programs, I have installed Window List. The latter works well, with one exception: You can switch workspaces by scrolling the mouse wheel over the thumbnail pictures; unfortunately, the area to the right of the thumbnails is now not included as it used to be when this extension was positioned in the corner, displaying "n/m" instead of the thumbnails. See the attached picture, where the area now NOT reacting to the mouse wheel is given.

[image: non-reactive area]

The reason I object to this is of course that placing the cursor in the corner is so easy to do.

I thought this would be a GNOME issue, so I contacted the people at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions to seek help. Unfortunately, the issue I raised there was eventually closed with the label `Not GNOME`: the developers could not reproduce this behaviour.

The question is: can I restore the scroll behaviour in the corner, and how?

Update:
Just to add to the confusion: I have three laptops, and on the third (an old HP Pavilion), there is no problem. The Thumbnails are displayed flush right there, and scrolling works.

I'm wondering if the graphics driver can somehow be the culprit. Don't know how to further investigate this, maybe a pointer from someone?

Comment: Also to me, this looks like an issue that is related to the extension. Filing an issue with the developpers of the extension is probably the way to proceed.

Comment: @vanadium This extension is officially supported by Gnome, so the developers are indeed the ones I have contacted. With most extensions a direct connection to the developer is easy to accomplish, but unfortunately not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed - an update to the extension in question now has the buttons flush right on my screen(s), and everything works. Thanks to the programmer :)